# "No graph view available" on Firefox

Tags: neo4j

I got

```
No graph view available. You have to RETURN  nodes, relationships or paths to see a graph visualization.
```

for every single query using Firefox.
The same queries work fine on Chrome.

It's not that I don't want to use Chrome, I want to know why neo4j behaves like that on Firefox.

Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox 38, JavaScript enabled, Neo4j 2.1.3 and 2.2.2
Query example:

```
match (n) return n;
```

Comment: Can you see something in the javascript console?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I got "TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.". Any idea?

Comment: Which version of Neo4j?

Comment: @akollegger I tried both Neo4j 2.1.3 and 2.2.2

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce this and have never heard of it before this.  
Can you try to clear the browser cache and reload by hitting `Ctrl` + `F5` or `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R` and try again?